# Performance of Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

We are building an application, in which one of the assets will have a concept array of 10,000 records. We need to know, what could be the performance time for this asset retrieval.

**Sample Asset Type**.

```
    {
      "$class": "org.example.basic.Asset",
      "userId": "pradeep",
      "companyName": "ABC",
      "records": [
        {
          "$class": "org.example.basic.Record",
          "recordId": "1",
          "recordName": "record1",
          "recordType": "Manual",
          "dateCommitted": "2018-09-21T12:38:04.464Z",
           "skills": [
            {
              "$class": "org.example.basic.Skill",
              "skillLevel": "BASIC",
              "Langauge": "Node.js"
            },
             {
              "$class": "org.example.basic.Skill",
              "skillLevel": "EXPERT",
              "Langauge": "Java"
            }
          ]
    },
 {
          "$class": "org.example.basic.Record",
          "recordId": "2",
          "recordName": "record2",
          "recordType": "Auto",
          "dateCommitted": "2018-09-21T12:38:04.464Z",
           "skills": [
            {
              "$class": "org.example.basic.Skill",
              "skillLevel": "BASIC",
              "Langauge": "Node.js"
            },
             {
              "$class": "org.example.basic.Skill",
              "skillLevel": "EXPERT",
              "Langauge": "Java"
            }
          ]
    },]
    }
```

There will be 10,000 records and 1000 skills. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anybody will be able to answer you question of performance time.  It will depend partly on your coding, but mostly on your Fabric design/configuration and your available hardware.

Testing on a variety of Fabric and Hardware configurations may help you.

You might also want to look at [Hyperledger Caliper](https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper) for performance testing.

I'm not sure from the example data - but are you including an array of 1000 concepts in a single Asset?  That seems like a lot to manage and retrieve/search through.

Looking at your number of 10,000 records - are you developing a prototype.demo or POC?

Have you seen [this announcement regarding Composer](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125)?  I think that most people will now regard Composer as a good vehicle for demo/ptototype/POC, but not for Production where performance and long term support are required.